# Umbraco Cannot render a macro when there is no current PublishedContentRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

Hope you can help me.I encountered that error upon calling a view from my umbraco razor page using RenderMvcController. It's seems it can't render my created macro inside a layout page.

Line 4:  }
Line 5:
Line 6:  @Umbraco.RenderMacro("ExternalRedirect")
Line 7:
Line 8:

Source File: c:\Working\Git\ID\UMB Packages\Website\Views\Default.cshtml    Line: 6

Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Cannot render a macro when there is no
>   current PublishedContentRequest.]
>   Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper.RenderMacro(String alias, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +142    ASP._Page_Views_Default_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\Working\Git\ID\UMB Packages\Website\Views\Default.cshtml:6
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +125
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +196
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +89
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String
>   partialViewName, Action`1 body) +233
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +287
>   Umbraco.Core.Profiling.ProfilingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer) +140
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +378    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.b__17()
>   +33    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   +799724    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   +799724    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +263
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +787092
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +15    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +65
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +15    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +51
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +15    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +51
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +606    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

```
public class BlogController : RenderMvcController
{
   public BlogController()
       : this(UmbracoContext.Current)
   {
   }

   public BlogController(UmbracoContext umbracoContext)
       : base(umbracoContext)
   {
   }

   public ActionResult Index(int id)
   {
       return View("12321");
   }

   public ActionResult YearPost(int id)
   {
       string test = "Blog";
       var criteria = ExamineManager.Instance.DefaultSearchProvider.CreateSearchCriteria("content");
       var filterBlogs = id == 0 ? criteria.NodeTypeAlias("Blog") : criteria.NodeName("Blog");
       var result = Umbraco.TypedSearch(filterBlogs.Compile()).ToArray().First();

       var renderModel = CreateRenderModel(result);
       string viewBlog = "BlogPostPage";
       return View(viewBlog, renderModel);
   }
   private RenderModel CreateRenderModel(IPublishedContent content)
   {
       var model = new RenderModel(content,CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);

       //add an umbraco data token so the umbraco view engine executes
       RouteData.DataTokens["umbraco"] = model;
       RouteData.DataTokens["umbraco-doc-request"] = UmbracoContext.PublishedContentRequest;
       RouteData.DataTokens["umbraco-context"] = UmbracoContext;
       return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you update question with view files

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this one ? I am facing the same issue after migrating to version 7.5.4 from 7.1.4